# comparison function on bsearch() c

Tags: c

I'm struggling to do my comparison function in bsearch() on my code. 
Apparently,I want to do binary search based on the key string (from linked list) on the dictionary array that contains structs (word_dict_t)

```
typedef struct {
    word_t name;
    probarr_t prob;
} word_dict_t;
```

Here's the comparison function that I made:

```
int cmp_func(const void *source, const void *dest) {
   const word_dict_t *dest_struct = (word_dict_t *)dest;
   return strcmp((const char*)source, dest_struct->name);
}
```

This is the implementation of bsearch() function:

```
void categorize(list_t *list, word_dict_t dictionary[], int *num_dict) {
    int i=0;
    word_dict_t *result;
    word_t key;

    printf("%sSTAGE 4%s\n", LINE_STG, LINE_STG);

    while (!is_empty_list(list)){
        strcpy(key, *get_head(list));
        list=get_tail(list);

        result = (word_dict_t *) bsearch(key, dictionary, *num_dict,
                       sizeof(word_t),cmp_func);
        if (result==NULL){
            printf("%-32s NOT_NAME \n", key);
        }
        else{
            print_probabilities(result);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

word_t is a char array holding the word.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: note: the dictionary array is already sorted alphabetically (ascending)

Answer (score 3):

`bsearch()` needs to know the size of each element in the array. It gets passed as a pointer, so `bsearch()` needs to know how to calculate the offset of each element.

When `bsearch()` tries to find the `nth` element of the array it will do something like:

```
ptr + size * n;
```

(Where `ptr` is the 2nd param to `bsearch()` and `size` is the 4th).

So if you provide the wrong `size` value (which you are doing), `bsearch()` won't be able to calculate the correct addresses.

Fix - pass the correct size of the elements of the array:

```
result = bsearch(key, dictionary, *num_dict, sizeof(word_dict_t), cmp_func);
```

or:

```
result = bsearch(key, dictionary, *num_dict, sizeof(dictionary[0]), cmp_func);
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>Your comparison function will be passed (as `void *`) pointers to 2 elements of the array. Your comparison function must treat both of these pointers equivalently - the normal way is to define 2 local variables of type "pointer-to-array-element", and assign (without casts) the two arguments to those local variables; then compare the 2 elements by dereferencing those local, appropriate-type pointers.</del>

<del>Your sample comparison function converts the two arguments into pointers-to 2 diferent types. You're going to have a bad time.</del>

Ignore the above.

(While `bsearch()` *can* use a comparison function that is also usable by `qsort()`, it isn't necessary to write the function that way.)

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect: [_key is passed as the first argument, an element from the array as the second._](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch)

Comment: Fair point, @JohnnyMopp. I've spent too much time with `qsort()`, not enough with `bsearch()`.